# How to combine multiple static libraries when the library name contains a space?

Tags: linux, static-libraries, unix-ar

I am working on various flavors of Linux and I need to combine multiple static libraries such as

```
foo1.a
foo bar.a
foo2.a
```

into one single combo static library (note that the second file has a space in it's name).

I've seen stackoverflow articles that explain how to do this with an `ar mri` script. The suggestion is to create a file named `combine.ar` with contents such as

```
CREATE comboLib.a
ADDLIB foo1.a
ADDLIB foo bar.a
ADDLIB foo2.a
VERBOSE
SAVE
END
```

And then use the command `ar -M < combine.ar`.

However, the ar script language treats spaces as a way to add two items, so it sees the second line as add library foo and library bar.a

I've tried the following with no luck

```
ADDLIB "foo bar.a"
ADDLIB foo\ bar.a
ADDLIB 'foo bar.a'
```

How can this be done?

Comment: A simple workaround might be to rename or symlink the library `foo bar.a` to a name without a space.

Comment: Now you know one more reason not to use file names (or path names) with spaces in them when programming.  It wreaks havoc, sooner rather than later.  Stick to the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) defined by POSIX — which consists of the (unaccented Latin) alphanumeric characters, underscore, dash, dot.  Anything else is risky — sooner or later, you'll run into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible to use file names with a space in a MRI script. You can rename or symlink the library file `foo bar.a` to a name without space as a simple workaround.

If you don't insist on using a MRI script you can do this with a series of `ar` commands.

The following script assumes that all library files are in the same directory and the temporary directory does not conflict with something else.

```
for lib in foo1.a 'foo bar.a' foo2.a
do
  rm -rf tmpdir   # make sure we do not have any existing file
  mkdir tmpdir    # place to extract members
  cd tmpdir
  # x = extract all memebers, o = keep original file date
  ar xo ../"$lib"
  # r = add/replace member, c = create archive without warning
  ar rc ../comboLib.a *
done
rm -rf tmpdir     # clean up
```

Edit: As modern systems don't need `ranlib`, I removed the `s` modifier from the `ar r` command.

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar

Comment: You should probably run `ranlib` to create (cleanup?) the indexes after the archive is created.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `ranlib`, @jww.  Modern versions of `ar` automatically do the relevant indexing job.